# Web logic 10.3.6 error NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, weblogic

I`ve deployed an Esri COTS application on top of web logic 10.3.6, it works properly.

I updated a class inside a JAR file then recompiled the class and replaced it in the JAR.

When I tried to start the Admin server again, I got the following error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/esri/gpt/framework/security/identity/SingleSignOnMechanism

Note that the class SingleSignOnMechanism exists in the JAR and compiled without errors or warnings.

Please advice.

Comment: Where does the jar live? In a war file? Have you uninstalled/redeployed your app after the change?

Comment: The jar is in WEB-INF\lib. i just build and clean in netbeans. stop and start web logic